# ValueError when trying to start carbon-cache

Tags: graphite

I have an issue with **Graphite**, specifically with carbon-cache. At some point I had it running. now when coming back after a few weeks I tried to start graphite again. The django-webapp runs fine but it seems I have an issue with the carbon-cache backend. Graphite is installed in /opt/graphite and I run /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start. This is the error I get:

```
root@stfutm01:/opt/graphite/bin# ./carbon-cache.py start
Starting carbon-cache (instance a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./carbon-cache.py", line 30, in <module>
    run_twistd_plugin(__file__)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py", line 92, in run_twistd_plugin
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 386, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 446, in createOrGetApplication
    ser = plg.makeService(self.config.subOptions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/twisted/plugins/carbon_cache_plugin.py", line 21, in makeService
    return service.createCacheService(options)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/service.py", line 127, in createCacheService
    from carbon.writer import WriterService
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/writer.py", line 34, in <module>
    schemas = loadStorageSchemas()
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/storage.py", line 123, in loadStorageSchemas
    archives = [ Archive.fromString(s) for s in retentions ]
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/storage.py", line 107, in fromString
    (secondsPerPoint, points) = whisper.parseRetentionDef(retentionDef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whisper.py", line 76, in parseRetentionDef
    (precision, points) = retentionDef.strip().split(':')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I see that it as an issue with the split `retentionDef.strip().split(':')`. My storage schema config file (/opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf) looks like:

```
[stats]
priority = 110
pattern = ^stats\..*
retentions = 10s:6h,1m:7d,10m:1y
[ts3]
priority = 100
pattern = ^skarp\.ts3\..*
retentions = 60s:1y,1h,:5y
```

Any hints where I should looking? Or does anybody know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the [ts3] rentions.  "[The retentions line can specify multiple retentions. Each retention of frequency:history is separated by a comma.](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-schemas-conf)"

In ts3 it appears to be 3 retentions (comma-delimited), with the second not specifying a history and the last not specifying a frequency.

```
retentions = 60s:1y,1h,:5y
```

I think you may have meant:

```
retentions = 60s:1y,1h:5y
```

Which would be 60 second data for 1 year and 1 hour data for 5 years after that.

Comment: Jep, that was it. Somehow I got that comma in there and didn't see it. Thanks a lot that solved it.